# Setting up a working DataTables export in JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, datatables, tabletools

I'm having a very difficult time getting export to CSV/Excel/PDF working in JSFiddle. Please see [my attempted JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/6b74w/64/)

When I look at the JavaScript console for http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/6b74w/64/show/light/ I see

> GET
>   http://fiddle.jshell.net/jhfrench/6b74w/64/show/light/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf
>   404 (NOT FOUND)        ZeroClipboard.js:52

This error surprises me because I thought I set the path to the SWF file with this code:

```
...
"oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
...
```

How can I get [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/6b74w/64/) to demonstrate the export features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The problem seems to be with TableTools's support of [jQuery "multiple" selectors](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/). My original selector (`$('#browser_data, #task_list')`) results in the default (and unavailable) SWF path.

When I change the selector to `$('#task_list')` it works.

See [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/6b74w/). Note that the second table is no longer enhanced with DataTable plugin.

Of course, if you want to call DataTables on multiple tables, with TableTools enabled, you can always use this jQuery syntax:

```
$('#task_list, #browser_data').each( function() {
        $(this).dataTable({ ...your options here etc...});
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/6b74w/308/ for multiple tables enhanced by DataTables/TableTools.

Comment: For cross-referencing, I contributed similar posts to the official DataTables forum at http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15341/setting-up-a-working-export-in-jsfiddle

Comment: The buttons for exporting don't appear it seems

Comment: @Maxrunner: the downside to hotlinking. I updated the jsFiddle includes to point to CDN-hosted scripts. Give it a shot now.